# How to random a file from a dir within static dir?

Tags: django, file, random, static

I have such structure.

```
~/app/static/ tree -L 2
.
├── css
│   ├── jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom
│   └── styles.css
├── img
│   └── funny
├── js
│   ├── jquery-ui-1.10.3
│   └── jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
├── privacy-policy.html
└── tou.html
```

I'd like to show user a random file from img/funny.
How can I do that?

I can put a css of js file in template, like:

```
  <script src="{% static "js/jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-1.9.1.js" %}"></script>
```

but I have no idea how to random a file from subdir of static dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random, glob
path = random.choice(glob.glob('~/app/static/img/funny/*.*'))
```

Now in the path variable you'll have a path of a random file from *img/funny*

You might want to do the following if you want the path to be relative to *~/app/static/*

```
path = path.replace("~/app/static/","")
```

And then you can use it in your templates like:

```
<img src="{{ path }}"/>
```

Comment: How about moving project to production? What then?

Comment: Can you please explain what is the problem in moving the code to production?

Comment: I was concerned about many hardcoded paths, but I can create variables in settings.py, so accepted :)